# BlackBerry ConnectionFactory timeout

Tags: blackberry, timeout, connection

I upgraded an existing application and in the new version I **require OS 5** - one of the reasons was that I wanted to use **ConnectionFactory** for communicating via HTTP/HTTPS with our server without having to add all the URL parameters for using BES, BIS, Direct TCP, Wifi and so on.

The **ConnectionFactory** is now configured to choose the best way to connect to our services via preferred types.

My connection code looks like this:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
BisBOptions bisOptions = new BisBOptions(BIS_SECRET);
connectionFactory.setTransportTypeOptions(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, bisOptions);
connectionFactory.setConnectionMode(ConnectionFactory.ACCESS_READ_WRITE);
connectionFactory.setEndToEndDesired(true);
connectionFactory.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[] { TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS,
TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR });
ConnectionDescriptor connectionDescriptor = connectionFactory.getConnection("https://myserver.com/serviceurl");
try {
  HttpConnection con = (HttpConnection) connectionDescriptor.getConnection();
  byte[] bytes = parameter.toString().getBytes(UTF_8);
  con.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(bytes.length));
  os = con.openOutputStream();
  os.write(bytes);
  os.flush();
  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode == 401) {
    throw new InvalidCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
  } else if (responseCode != 200 && responseCode != 500) {
    EventLogger.logEvent(RTSID, ("Response code " + responseCode + " " + con
          .getResponseMessage()).getBytes(), EventLogger.ERROR);
    EventLogger.logEvent(RTSID, bytes, EventLogger.ERROR);
    throw new IOException("Invalid request");
  }
  is = con.openInputStream();
  if (is != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int c = 0;
    try {
      c = is.read();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      c = -1;
    }
    while (c >= 0) {
      baos.write(c);
      try {
        c = is.read();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        c = -1;
      }
    }
    String response = new String(baos.toByteArray(), UTF_8);
    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject;
      if (response.startsWith("[")) {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(ARRAY, new JSONArray(response));
      } else {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
      }
      if (responseCode == 500) {
        throw new Exception(jsonObject.getString("message"));
      }
      return jsonObject;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      EventLogger.logEvent(RTSID, ("Exception occured: " + e.toString()).getBytes(),
      EventLogger.ERROR);
    }
  }
} finally {
  if (is != null) {
    try {
      is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
  if (os != null) {
    try {
      os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
  if (con != null) {
    try {
      con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that this works not as well as when I added the connection parameters to my URL manually. I get errors in the server logs looking like the clients close the connection after some kind of timeout.

Here are some log examples:

```
93.186.30.120 - - [28/Jun/2012:15:50:08 +0200] "POST /service/methodX HTTP/1.1" 400 145 "-" "myapp VendorID/301" 10012567 
93.186.22.118 - - [28/Jun/2012:16:30:56 +0200] "POST /service/methodY HTTP/1.1" 400 145 "-" "myapp VendorID/137" 10012435
74.82.68.35 - - [28/Jun/2012:16:53:23 +0200] "POST /service/methodZ HTTP/1.1" 400 145 "-" "myapp BlackBerry9650/6.0.0.524 VendorID/105" 10012644
```

The IP Adresses are from **RIM Networks** - so these are Connections comming from **BIS**

Those connections got status code **400 (Bad Request)** from the server

The large numbers at the end of the line (e.g. 10012644) show the **time the request was processed** on the server in microseconds: 10012644 = about 10 seconds

Do the RIM servers add a connection timeout of **10 seconds**? That seems fairly short!

The problem is difficult to reproduce - has anybody experienced something like that before?

Comment: Timeout used to be 2 min. using HttpConnection alone. BTW, you probably will want to override this by calling `ConnectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout`. And about the 400, did you forget anything in the request? (like, for instance, HTTP headers like SoapAction). Do you have the certificates for https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. Problem was caused by default configuration of Apache module mod_reqtimeout:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>

# mod_reqtimeout limits the time waiting on the client to prevent an
# attacker from causing a denial of service by opening many connections
# but not sending requests. This file tries to give a sensible default
# configuration, but it may be necessary to tune the timeout values to
# the actual situation. Note that it is also possible to configure
# mod_reqtimeout per virtual host.


# Wait max 20 seconds for the first byte of the request line+headers
# From then, require a minimum data rate of 500 bytes/s, but don't
# wait longer than 40 seconds in total.
# Note: Lower timeouts may make sense on non-ssl virtual hosts but can
# cause problem with ssl enabled virtual hosts: This timeout includes
# the time a browser may need to fetch the CRL for the certificate. If
# the CRL server is not reachable, it may take more than 10 seconds
# until the browser gives up.
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500

# Wait max 10 seconds for the first byte of the request body (if any)
# From then, require a minimum data rate of 500 bytes/s
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500

</IfModule>
```

I guess BlackBerry clients wer hit harder because sending request body via RIM BIS infrastructure takes longer.

Set the value to 100 seconds and monitoring if clients are still affected.